# Can't add JSONObjects into an array

Tags: java, json, parsing, arraylist

I am using [JSON simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse a JSON file. When I do so I get a `JSONArray`. But when I try to iterate through it and get its `JSONObject` elements I get an error.

This is my code:

```
JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);

List<JSONObject> elementsList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for (int i = 1; i < jsonData.size(); i++) {
     elementsList.addAll(jsonData.get(i)); // Here jsonData.get(i) is a JSONObject
}
```

I get the following errors in Eclipse:

- The method addAll(Collection) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments 
   (Object)
- Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Collection

Not sure what these mean and how to fix that.

Comment: What is the return type of `JSONArray#get(int)`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited my question. It is `addAll` in fact.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `jsonData.get(i)` is a `JSONObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSONArray#get(int)` has a return type of `Object` (because it is inherited from the raw type `ArrayList`). `List#addAll(Collection)` expects an argument of type `Collection`. The type `Object` is not convertible to a `Collection` without a type cast.

However, even if you were to cast the value returned by `get`, the underlying value would actually be a `JSONObject` and you'd get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

What you want is

```
elementsList.addAll(jsonData); //  outside the loop
```

since `JSONArray` is a subtype of `ArrayList` which is a `Collection`. You'll  get a warning about `jsonData` requiring an unchecked conversion, but you should be good assuming that you actually have `JSONObject` values inside your `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, json Data.get(i) is a JSONObject, thus, it's normal that you can't add it with addAll.
Basically, use `addAll` if you want to add a List and `add` if you want to add an object.

You could change your code to iterate through your jsonData with your for-loop using `add`.
On the other way, you could simply use `elementsList.addAll(jsonData)`

Answer (score 0):

try like that.

```
for (int i = 1; i < jsonData.size(); i++) {
 elementsList.add(jsonData.getJSONObject(i)); 
}
```

Comment: `jsonData` doesn't have a `getJSONObject` method

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, ArrayList.addAll() takes only java.util.Collection types and can't take JSONObject as input parameter,

Here is the extract from javadoc,

[public boolean addAll(Collection c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator. The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

In order to get all the JSONObjects into the list, **use add method as mentioned below insteadof addAll()**,

```
JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);

List<JSONObject> elementsList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for (int i = 1; i < jsonData.size(); i++) {
    elementsList.add(jsonData.get(i)); // Here jsonData.get(i) is a JSONObject
}
```

Comment: I tried to use `add` as well however it didn't work either. The compiler error in this case is `The method add(JSONObject) in the type List<JSONObject> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`

Comment: Ah I see.. If you are pretty sure that all the elements within JSONArray is going to be JSONObject, then use **jsonData.getJSONObject(index)** method insteadof jsonData.get(index)